# What does グパ mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, onomatopoeia

There is a sound グパ in this manga (a plant tries to eat someone and makes グパ sound), but I can't find it in dictionaries and understand what it means and how it can be translated. What does グパ mean? Is it just something like "A-a-a"?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a mimetic word that describes the wide opening of a mouth or "a mouth-like thing". Sometimes it also describes how a covering/husk is cracked, like a watermelon or a human head cracked by an axe.

The better-known variant is unvoiced くぱぁ, which was popularized in the last two decades or so, and clearly has a sexual connotation (google it yourself; NSFW). Voicing of く [makes it sound "rough"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54142/5010), and it also avoids the sexual connotation.

I'm sorry, I don't know how this is translated into English...