# What does "プラついてる" mean, and how to research similar weird lines?

Tags: meaning

For context, the three main characters are visiting a museum and being sneaky by doing it while their parents are out. I know the gist of the line is "We're the heretics for taking advantage of our parents being out on work and [プラついてる] since noon like this?" In my research I keep finding references to plastic, which doesn't seem right, and I don't know of any good sources of slang or common sayings.

> 親が仕事で外出してるのをいいことに、こうして昼間からプラついてる私たちの方が異端ってわけか。

Comment: Are you sure it's not ブラついてる? Also, including the title might help. (If it's part of the official subtitle or something like that, typos might be less likely.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

プラつく is one-time alternative of the verb ぶらつく, which is also contained in dictionaries. That in your sentence falls on the second usage of [this entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B6%E3%82%89%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F/).

Since ぶらつく is an onomatopoeia-related word (cf. ぶらぶら), such a change in sound is relatively easy to be accepted/understood, even though highly rhetorical.

Comment: If ぶらつく is "to stroll around" and [non-voiced sounds are perceived as more feminine](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54141), perhaps プラつく is "to prance around"?

Comment: ぶらつく/ぷらつく or ぶらぶら/ぷらぷら are not an imitation of any actual sound, so the quoted discussion is difficult to apply directly. [This](https://whitebear0930.net/archives/21875) or any other articles describing difference between ぶらぶら/ぷらぷら(/ふらふら) probably help us understand their nuances. I personally feels ぷらぷら/ぷらつく puts more emphasis on freeness and haphazardness compared with ぶらぶら/ぶらつく.